# Is case statement1 + statement2: poor coding?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, c++98

I have written a switch statement that looks like this:

```
switch(statement){
    case statement1:
        break;
    case statement2:
        break;
    case statement3:
        break;
    case statement4:
        break;
    case statement1 + statement2:
        break;
    case statement1 + statement3:
        break;
    case statement1 + statement4:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

with the statements defined in the header like this:
    `#define statement1    999`
    `#define statement2    32898`
    `#define statement3    32899`
    `#define statement4    32900`
This compiles and works fine using visual studio 2003.

For me this is providing more statements with out the need to define more variables. Allowing me to have different options depending on what statements have been selected in previous code.

How does the community perceive this code? Accepted? Bad practice? Avoidable?

The only risk I can see is if there is ever a definition 33897,33898,33899.

Comment: The rule is that case labels need to be compile-time numerical constants, basically. What you ask about is more a matter of personal style, and that's a very subjective question and not really a good fit here on SO.

Comment: An if-else statement would seem much nicer to me.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh no, this is very objectively awful. It will silently fail in all kinds of scenarios (a) because the constants aren’t power of 2 flags, so their addition doesn’t yield unique values, and (b) making them macros rather than constant leads to name pollution.

Comment: Those are not statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, although I don't like switches, I think your code could be improved a lot.

First, using operators in switches is not wrong. You can use any kind of constexpr things you want. Operations on integers are constexpr.

The thing I would change is this:

```
const int statement1 = 999;
const int statement2 = 32898;
const int statement3 = 32899;
const int statement4 = 32900;
```

I would use `constexpr` if c++11 was available.

Macros can hide shady stuff, such as function call and complex operation. Now they are ints, usable at compile time.

Beside, the constants are hard to read, especially with those names­. You could generate, at compile time, the value of these constants using constexpr functions, or simply give them a better name and maybe commenting it.

Adding integers together in switch statement is not bad in practice, but as you said, the only risk I can see is if there is ever a definition 33897, 33898, 33899. This is why you should give meaning to the result of those operation. If 33897 is really the value you want to test, then do this:

```
const int combine2 = statement1 + statement2;
const int combine3 = statement1 + statement3;
```

You can define those in your very function if you don't want them in your global scope.

Comment: Like the other answer, this one suffers from a bad choice of numeric constants.

Comment: I took the constants OP has given to us. I could add something to the answer that could tell that.

Comment: My point is that these constants are bad, and they are actually a worse problem than the use of macros so they *need* to be handled in a complete answer. The problem isn’t that the constants are hard to read. They **lead to errors** because they are not powers of two, so different combinations of constants will result in the same value.

Comment: `const int` would work too. Or is there an advantage in using `constexpr int`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm not able to use C++11. The constants are as they are from MFC button allocation such as `#define ID_FILE_ABORT 32774`

Comment: @alain The advantage of using `constexpr` is that it's much more clearer that you really meant "a constant available at compile time" whereas there are places I used global const ints where the value was not usable at compile time. Bonus: in static members in C++17, constexpr will be declared as inline. not consts.

Comment: @StevoStephenson That's an important thing to know! I'll edit the tag of the question.

Comment: @StevoStephenson You need to update. You are using more than ten year old software that's outdated by at least five major product releases.

Answer (score 3):

Try avoiding #define whenever possible. Yes, that is a bad practice.

You could do it with constexpr:

```
constexpr int statement1 = 2;
```

and you can do exactly the same thing. But you get more expressiveness and type safety.

Comment: But see my caveat under the question. Using `constexpr` is only part of the necessary change.

Comment: VC++2003 does not support C++11.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It does, but not completely.
In a switch you must only use compile-time constants, and you do it. But as subjective opinion, I would create the sums (element1 + element2) either as define or constexpr outside the switch with other names and have the labels in the switch witout "+"

Comment: @LeDYoM You misunderstand. The problem is that the numerical values chosen here don't create unique combinations, unlike, say, powers of two. If OP adds statement5=32901, the code breaks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The compiler will detect and give an error if the numerical values are not unique; and thus it is not a problem. Using a nested if-statement the same problem will go undetected, which is worse.

Comment: @HansOlsson Is this diagnostic required? I didn't think so but I may be wrong.

Comment: Duplicate case-values has been an error since K&R. In one version C-standard it says: "The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same switch statement shall have the same value
after conversion." and in C++: "No two of the case constants in the same switch shall have the same value after conversion to the promoted type of the switch condition."

Comment: @KonradRudolph: N4296 has it in 6.4.2/2: *"No two of the case constants in the same switch shall have the same value after conversion."*

Comment: @ChristianHackl Ah, good then.